# How to Highlight all duplicate occurrences

Tags: google-sheets

I'am using this in Conditional formatting:

```
=if(B:B="","",or(COUNTIF(B:B, B1) > 1, NOT(COUNTIF(B$1:B1, B1) = 1), COUNTIF(B1:B, B1) >= 2))
```

Can anyone suggest else ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the names dataset (excluding the headers)
2. Click the Format option in the menu
3. In the options that show up, click on Conditional
   formatting.
4. Click on the ‘Add another rule’ option
5. Make sure the range (where we need to highlight the duplicates) is correct. In case it isn’t, you can change it from the ‘Apply to range’ section
6. Click on the ‘Format cells if’ drop-down and then click on the ‘Custom formula is’ option
7. In the field below, enter the following formula:

   ```
   =COUNTIF($A$2:$C$10,A2)>1
   ```
8. From the ‘Formatting style’ options, specify the formatting in which you want to highlight the duplicate cells. By default, it will use the green color, but you can specify other colors as well as styles such as bold or italics.
9. Click on Done

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this article can help with your problem:
[How to Highlight Duplicates In Google Sheets (Easy Steps)](https://productivityspot.com/highlight-duplicates-google-sheets/)

It provides good information and details on the type of query you are making.

To summarize, the formula `=countif($X$1:$R$2,X1)>1` should provide what you are looking for. Where X1 and X2 are the cells you are searching between given that you are looking for duplicates within a single column. This solution is the solution detailed further in section one of the linked article.